# Javascript toFixed() no trailing zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

I'm tired and this is maths. Should be fairly simple, and good chance I get it while typing this out.

I have a function, let's call it roundNumber

```
function roundNumber(value){
    return value.toFixed(3);
}
```

But I want to round to 3 decimal, unless the succeeding digits are 0.
Desired result:

```
roundNumber(1/3) //Should output 0.333
roundNumber(1/2) //Should output 0.5, NOT 0.500
roundNumber(1/8) //Should output 0.125
roundNumber(1/4) //Should output 0.25
```

Best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off: What the function does is **not** just rounding. It converts a number to a string (doing some rounding along the way).

If you really want a string, your best bet is probably to trim off trailing zeros that don't have a `.` in front of them:

```
return value.toFixed(3).replace(/([^.])0+$/, "$1");
```

Live Example:

```js
function roundNumber(value) {
    return value.toFixed(3).replace(/([^.])0+$/, "$1");
}
console.log(roundNumber(1/3)); //Should output 0.333
console.log(roundNumber(1/2)); //Should output 0.5, NOT 0.500
console.log(roundNumber(1/8)); //Should output 0.125
console.log(roundNumber(1/4)); //Should output 0.25
```

Answer (score 4):

To do what you require you can convert the string result of `toFixed()` back to a numerical value.

The example below uses the [`+` unary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus) to do this, but `Number()` or `parseFloat()` would work just as well.

```js
function roundNumber(value) {
  return +value.toFixed(3);
}

console.log(roundNumber(1 / 3)) //Should output 0.333
console.log(roundNumber(1 / 2)) //Should output 0.5, NOT 0.500
console.log(roundNumber(1 / 8)) //Should output 0.125
console.log(roundNumber(1 / 4)) //Should output 0.25
```

Comment: This is assuming the OP wants a number (which they may, but it's not what their function currently returns). I've gone the other way (assuming they really want a string). So we've got it covered. :-)

Comment: `+value.toFixed(3)` to `+(+value).toFixed(3)` allows number or string of `value`